# Python Wand get Offset from Trim

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I'm using Wand in Python for manipulating my images.  I'm using the .trim() function to auto-crop these images.

The resulting image gives me the new size, obviously.  But I can't figure out how to get the offset from the original image.

The documentation is pretty sparse.

In Imagemagick, you can use :info and you get the offset for trim (and the new size).

Is there a way to get the offset information using Wand?

Comment: I looked through the code (wand.py) and it looks like it's using the the api for MagickWand.c. The "trim() call" to going to the "MagickTrimImage" method.  Hopefully this helps.  http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickWand/magick-image_8c_source.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wand.image.Image.page`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.page) which will return the size + offset.

```py
with Image(filename="input.png") as img:
    img.trim()
    offset = img.page[2:]  # => (x, y)
```

There's also `page_x` & `page_y` properties introduced in version 0.4.3.

Comment: This works perfect! I had to install 0.4 like you said. But it works!